# How can I change the week starting day in Date picker of Google Calendar add-on?

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a Date Picker field in a Google Calendar Add-on. Here, the week start from a Sunday. Can I change this so that the week starts from a Monday ? [image]

Here is the code I am using to add a Date picker -

```
const today = new Date();
const tomorrow = new Date(today);
tomorrow.setDate(tomorrow.getDate() + 1);  
var startDatePicker = CardService.newDatePicker()
                      .setTitle("Start Date")
                      .setFieldName("start_date") 
                      .setValueInMsSinceEpoch(tomorrow.getTime())   
                      .setOnChangeAction(CardService.newAction().setFunctionName("dateStartCheck"));
```

This code is currently giving me a calendar where a week is Sunday-Saturday. Expectation is that the week should be Monday-Sunday.

Comment: How did you create the Date Picker? Whenever possible, you need to include a minimal example that reproduces the issue. You can also include the expected behavior, the actual behavior, and how they differ, that would be helpful as well. Please visit [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) have some tips on how to write a question, so the community will be able to help you out in a better way.

Comment: This is upadted

Comment: It seems that this is a product limitation, this request can be promoted for future development through [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/support#developer_product_feedback).